Effect of distance between CUDA threads in block?
I have a naive question about GPU programming. (ChatGPT and Claude didn't really give me a convincing answer. Maybe I'm prompting badly.)
GPU programming languages like CUDA and OpenCL organise threads in (using Nvidia terminology) a 3D block structure, and blocks in a 3D grid.   I know that this is convenient and natural for computer graphics. But I wonder if the 'distance' (see below for a definition) of two threads in a block, or two blocks in a grid, has any technical  effects for the performance of thread-execution?
What I mean is that there is a natural distance between two threads T1, and T2 in the same block at block   indices

T1 at (x1, y1, z1)
T2  at (x2, y2, z2)

The natural distance is the 3-dimensional euclidean distance (but other choices are possible).
Does this distance have any hardware effects? (E.g. if T1 and T2 are close then they can commuicate faster?) I think the answer is negative, but I could not find a convincing explanation online.
A similar question can be asked about the distance of blocks in a grid.

The dimensionality is just an abstraction. On the hardware level only one thing counts for the "distance" between threads of the same block and that is if they are part of the same warp which then enables the use of warp intrinsics for faster communication (which is mostly not done automatically by the compiler. Warp-aggregated atomics are an exception to that rule I think.).

For the Hopper architecture there is a way to access the shared memory of other blocks in the same thread block cluster (which corresponds to SMs grouped within a "GPC" in hardware). But again the "distance" has nothing to do with the 3D coordinates of blocks withing the cluster or clusters within the grid as far as I know.

The one thing where 3D distance plays a role is when using texture memory access. But that is about the distance between addresses, i.e. memory locality/caching, not about the distance between threads/blocks.

There might be (undocumented, not to be relied on, brittle, depending on the absence of concurrent work on the GPU) ways of predicting which blocks will be scheduled to the same SM (allowing them to "communicate faster" through L1). But like with the organization of threads in warps, I would think that the 3D block coordinates are just unrolled into a 1D index s.t. 3-dimensional distance is not of any help. Same goes for the locality in time of blocks that are part of the same "wave".

There are some reverse engineering papers such as Amert et.al: GPU Scheduling on the NVIDIA TX2: Hidden Details Revealed that indicate that, at least in the hardware they inspected, thread blocks are assigned round-robin. For example if you have two SMs, each able to run two blocks at the same time, the first SM gets blocks 0 and 2 while the second gets blocks 1 and 3.

I think this behavior makes sense and will remain even on newer hardware because it improves edge cases such as when you have fewer blocks than resources. Then you would rather want both SMs being half-full rather than one SM being full and one being empty. W.R.T. x-y-z order, I think it is fair to assume that the scheduling order follows the same pattern used for threads within a block. Meaning adjacent x values are close together; adjacent z values are spread apart

I did a quick test looking at the %smid and clock to inspect the scheduling. See here on godbolt. Scheduling across SMs seems a bit more chaotic and not exactly round-robin. However, the second part that adjacent x values are scheduled at similar times and z values are spread out, does seem true.

@paleonix Thanks. But unrolling a 3D structure into 1D does not change the fact that the threads are totally ordered. (Indeed, the 3D Euclidean distance induces a 1D Euclidean distance.) It could be (or not be) that the 1D distance guarantees something in hardware. At least in principle.

The order of the threads can have an impact on performance depending on your kernel but in most case, I do not think this is really relevant to focus on that (i.e. it certainly not worth the effort at all). Such thing can change from one architecture to another, and possibly even one device to another or worst...

@JérômeRichard Thanks. I am not suggesting that it is good practise / or worth the effort. I am just wondering if the hardware makes any guarantees about this. In other words, I'm trying to understand the exact semantics of Cuda, OpenCL etc.

The order of the block matters, yes. A cached memory access of a given block can make subsequent block computation faster. If the scheduling is inefficient, the cache can be trashed and data reloaded over and over inefficiently (saturating the VRAM and increasing the latency of RAM memory accesses). Generally, the best is to avoid the execution time to be too sensitive to that. For example, by avoiding data to be reloaded multiple time by many different blocks (see thread coarsening for example).

AFAIK, block scheduling is clearly not specified (both on Nvidia GPU and AMD ones). Actually, GPUs typically execute several blocks concurrently per SM: when the GPU stall on an instruction like a VRAM load (due to its high latency), it just executes another block and put the previous one in a waiting state. The same can happen with many different kind of instructions, even math ones. Since the latency is hardware-dependent and the content of the cache is rather impracticable on a parallel device, the exact scheduling is rather impracticable too.

You should care about warps first, and regarding blocks, I advise you to make blocks as independent as possible. If there is any order in which blocks are executed faster, then you can often rewrite your kernel to manually merge blocks so to benefit from that at the expense of less parallelism (which can impact performance if you do not have enough parallelism already).

You probably have something like the CPU core-to-core latency map in mind:

(source: https://www.anandtech.com/show/21124/amd-ryzen-threadripper-7980x-and-7970x-review/4)
The prerequisite is that the cores can communicate with each other - on a CPU they can. For GPUs there is no such map, because the streaming multipricessors on a GPU cannot communicate with each other. Communication is only possible from each SM to VRAM, and among the threads within each SM via shared memory (L1 cache).
The thread block coordinates you specify in software are not where thread blocks are executed on the hardware. The GPU scheduler dynamically assignes thread blocks to free SMs, and you have zero control over that on application side. 3D Euclidian distance is purely a software thing - the thread block coordinates all get linearized under the hood, so their 3D coordinates have no meaning other than from where to load the data. On the hardware level there might be latency differences between SMs, depending on their physical position on the chip and trace length to the memory controller, but you have no control over that either.

Thanks, that's roughly also what I thought, but I wanted to make sure.
